WebSocket Client in Flutter not Receiving Messages from Server (Netty WebSocket Server)
I am having trouble with WebSocket communication in my Flutter application. The server (using Netty) is successfully receiving the userId and responding with a message, but the Flutter WebSocket client is unable to receive any messages from the server.
What I’ve Done So Far:
Server Side (Netty WebSocket Server) Code:
The server is built using Netty, and the WebSocket server is set up as follows:
public class WebSocketServer {

private final int port;

public WebSocketServer(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public void start() throws InterruptedException {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
                        ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
                        pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
                        pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
                        pipeline.addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());
                        pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/ws"));
                        pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketFrameHandler());
                    }
                })
                .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        Channel channel = serverBootstrap.bind(port).sync().channel();
        System.out.println("WebSocket Server started on port " + port);
        channel.closeFuture().sync();
    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}

// WebSocketFrameHandler handles the incoming WebSocket frames.
public class WebSocketFrameHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<TextWebSocketFrame> {
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, TextWebSocketFrame msg) {
        // Print client info
        System.out.println("New client connected with userId: 1234 and assigned connectionId: " + ctx.channel().id().asLongText());

        // Send a message to the client
        ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame("Welcome user 1234! Your connection ID is: " + ctx.channel().id().asLongText()));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new WebSocketServer(8080).start();
}

}
The server is running on ws://localhost:8080/ws and sends the response "Welcome user 1234! Your connection ID is: " to the client.
Flutter Client Code:
In Flutter, I am using WebSocketChannel to connect to the WebSocket server and listen for messages:
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

class SocketWithNetty extends StatefulWidget {
  const SocketWithNetty({super.key});

  @override
  State<SocketWithNetty> createState() => _SocketIoNewState();
}

class _SocketIoNewState extends State<SocketWithNetty> {
  late WebSocketChannel _channel;
  late TextEditingController _controller;
  String _message = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initialize WebSocket connection
    _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('ws://localhost:8080/ws?userId=1234'));

    // Listen to WebSocket stream to receive messages
    _channel.stream.listen(
      (message) {
        setState(() {
          _message = message;
        });
      },
      onError: (error) {
        print("Error: $error");
      },
      onDone: () {
        print("WebSocket connection closed");
      },
    );

    _controller = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _channel.sink.close();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _channel.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('WebSocket Client')),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _sendMessage,
              child: Text('Send Message'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text('Server Response: $_message'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Problem:

The WebSocket connection is successfully established between the Flutter client and the Netty server.
The Flutter client can send messages to the server, but it does not receive any messages back from the server.
On the server side, I can see that the writeAndFlush method is called, and the message is being sent to the client. However, the Flutter client doesn’t receive the response.
What I’ve Tried:
Checked server logs – The server correctly logs that the client is connected and the message is sent to the client.
Verified WebSocket URL – I used the correct WebSocket URL (ws://localhost:8080/ws?userId=1234).
Checked Flutter WebSocket client – I used WebSocketChannel to connect and listen to the stream, but no data is received in the onData callback.
Used print() statements in Flutter to debug the incoming message, but it’s never printed.
Questions:
Why is the Flutter client not receiving the messages sent by the server?
Are there any specific WebSocket configurations I need to check or change on either the - - Flutter client or the server side?
Is there a known issue with WebSocket communication between a Netty server and Flutter?
Environment:
Flutter version: 3.x.x
WebSocket library: web_socket_channel
Server: Netty-based WebSocket server
Testing environment: Android/iOS emulator (with localhost or physical device with IP address)

